# How Can I strip HTML from Text in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery, html

I have an asp.net web page that has a TinyMCE box. Users can format text and send the HTML to be stored in a database.

On the server, I would like to take strip the html from the text so I can store only the text in a Full Text indexed column for searching.

It's a breeze to strip the html on the client using jQuery's text() function, but I would really rather do this on the server. Are there any existing utilities that I can use for this?

## EDIT

See my answer.

## EDIT 2

[alt text http://tinyurl.com/sillychimp](http://tinyurl.com/sillychimp)

Comment: Why use TinyMCE if you're just going to strip out all the formatting?!

Comment: I am storing the TinyMCE generated html so I can present formatted text back to the users. I am going to store the html-stripped text in a different column for full-text searching. I don't think it's a good idea to full text index/search a column that contains a ton of HTML. I didn't include these details in the original question, because it has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: +1 for making me laugth with this monkey

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I downloaded the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and created this function:

```
string StripHtml(string html)
{
    // create whitespace between html elements, so that words do not run together
    html = html.Replace(">","> ");

    // parse html
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();   
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    // strip html decoded text from html
    string text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(doc.DocumentNode.InnerText);   

    // replace all whitespace with a single space and remove leading and trailing whitespace
    return Regex.Replace(text, @"\s+", " ").Trim();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at richardtallent comment to your answer.

Comment: I saw it. I think I will just stick with the 5 lines of code I have written.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this [Strip HTML tags from a string using regular expressions](http://osherove.com/blog/2003/5/13/strip-html-tags-from-a-string-using-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: a better idea would be to use an html parser.

Comment: why if a simple regex do the job?

Comment: @mkoryak: Could you please explain why it would be better?

Comment: This will strip tags but leave entities HTML-encoded, so it's not really a complete answer.

Comment: To add to what richardtallent said: malformed HTML can break a regex and cause it to strip things it shouldn't. A full HTML parser is designed to accommodate malformed HTML so you don't lose data, or gain "extra" data.

Comment: I think that if you have a malformed HTML a good solution would be fix it before store it (HTML Tidy). A malformed HTML can break your layout, depending where you display it

Answer (score 4):

Check the following example:

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"Filepath");
string str = tr.ReadToEnd();     
str= Regex.Replace(str,"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty);
```

but you need to have a namespace referenced i.e:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

only take this logic for your website

Comment: RegEX is not the ideal choice for parsing RegEx.  See the comments to RioTera's answer, but short of it is if you have malformed HTML, RegEx will strip away the wrong data.

Comment: @psubsee2003 riotera just links out to an answer that recommends exactly the same Regex; one day that link will die and we'll be lucky this Answer has the Regex in it. This is the better answer.

Comment: @ChrisMoschini I never said that answer was better.  I said see the comments under that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's Jeff Atwood's RefactorMe code link for his [Sanitize HTML method](http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html)

Comment: And here's how he balances the tags so you don't end up with someone's user content closing a div on your page that it didn't open: http://refactormycode.com/codes/360-balance-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
string strwithouthtmltag;    
strwithouthtmltag = Regex.Replace(strWithHTMLTags, "<[^>]*>", string.Empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just storing text for indexing then you probably want to do a bit more than just remove the HTML, such as ignoring stop-words and removing words shorter than (say) 3 characters. However, a simple tag and stripper I once wrote goes something like this:

```
    public static string StripTags(string value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        string pattern = @"&.{1,8};";
        value = Regex.Replace(value, pattern, " ");
        pattern = @"<(.|\n)*?>";
        return Regex.Replace(value, pattern, string.Empty);
    }
```

It's old and I'm sure it can be optimised (perhaps using a compiled reg-ex?). But it does work and may help...

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Use a plain old TEXTAREA (styled for height/width/font/etc.) rather than TinyMCE.
- Use TinyMCE's built-in configuration options for stripping unwanted HTML.
- Use HtmlDecode(RegEx.Replace(mystring, "<[^>]+>", "")) on the server.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have malformed HTML in the system: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or similar could be used.

It is written in Python; I am not sure how it could be interfaced - using the .NET language IronPython?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTQL COM, and query the source with a query: 
<body> &tx;